# Consume multiple text files with Apache Flink DataSet API

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

I am writing a batch job with Apache Flink using the `DataSet` API. I can read a text file using `readTextFile()` but this function just read one file at once.

I would like to be able to consume all the text files in my directory one by one and process them at the same time one by one, in the same function as a batch job with the `DataSet` API, if it is possible.

Other option is implement a loop doing multiple jobs, one for each file, instead of one job, with multiples files. But I think this solution is not the best.

Any suggestion?

Comment: have you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

If I got the documentation right you can read an entire path using `ExecutionEnvironment.readTextFile()`. You can find an example here: [Word-Count-Batch-Example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/bb82aacf46565968359f5ee6d2503c3293d71d6e/flink-examples/flink-examples-batch/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/examples/java/wordcount/WordCount.java)

References:

- [Flink Documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/#data-sources)
- [Flink Sources](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/ExecutionEnvironment.java)